# Issues with Combo boxes

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have a database that I've converted over to 2007 Access.  I ended up rebuilding the Combo boxes.  They all work fine in the active databae however as soon as I close the database and reopen it - they don't work and a number of errors are displayed..

If I create a second combo the same way -Then both combos start working... but once again as soon as I've closed the database and reopen it.. they both stop working?

These are simply combo boxes that search the current FORM to find a record..

ie.. Field "Company Name" - Combo is searching for a particualar company record as entered or selected from the drop down combo box.

In the database settings / trustcentre I've switched on true all marcos etc.

What have I missed?

Comment: That one is going to tough to answer without more details. Like how are you binding the data to the combo boxes? What else is in play on the code behind for the form in question?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- try decompiling the project. It may have been corrupted.
  Just open your file from the command line and add the `/decompile` parameter.
  Then just rebuild your project and compact it.
- Make sure your references in the VBA IDE > Tools > References... contains the correct libraries:

  Visual Basic For Application
  Microsoft *Access* 12.0 Object Library
  OLE Automation
  Microsoft Office 12.0 Access database engine Object Library
  Microsoft *Office* 12.0 Object Library

The OLE Automation is sometimes source of strange issues: It sometimes gets automatically selected on my Windows Server 2008 x64 machine but I have to disable it on my Windows XP 32bit desktop...

Comment: There's really nothing in the OLE Automation library that I can imagine anyone needing (certainly not by default), so I always remove it. I would also eliminate the Office references -- they really aren't needed. And you omit any DAO reference (I don't know the name of it in A2K7).

Comment: Just noticed that I said DAO reference was omitted, but that's what "Access database engine Object Library" refers to, so it was omitted after all.